# Monte Carlo uncertainty analysis of actual and predicted data in R?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, descriptive-statistics, monte-carlo, uncertainty

I am a need of **Monte Carlo uncertainty analysis of actual and predicted data in R** I used a regression AI model to predict and now I would like to conduct Monte Carlo uncertainty analysis of actual and predicted data in R I saw this [click here for that](https://rdrr.io/rforge/metRology/man/uncertMC.html)
But challenging to understand the hyperparameters of it. Even not sure that This is related to my problem or not? Data is as follows: there are two columns one for Actual and another for Predicted value; see below [image]

many thanks!
best regards!

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to help you with this. With what model was the "predict" column created? Was it trained on the same data it is being tested on? Where does Monte Carlo come in? Normally "Monte Carlo" would suggest that you simulate a process with a bunch of random results, so the output would not be a single number but many different predictions and you could consider their distribution.

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to help you with this. (**Please ask what you need**) With what model was the "predict" column created? (**XGBoost**) Was it trained on the same data it is being tested on? (**I divided the data 80-20; 80% for training and 20% for testing**)

Comment: Where does Monte Carlo come in? (**For example, something like   [this published work](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1001627918303810) Please go to section 2.3 and 3.3.**) Normally "Monte Carlo" would suggest that you simulate a process with a bunch of random results, so the output would not be a single number but many different predictions and you could consider their distribution.

Comment: (**In last of the analysis something like this see figure no 6 of the mentioned paper I will have to draw the graph as a result to report **)